# Aufzählungen von Worten mit Auslassungszeichen

Tags: spelling, list

> Wollen Sie ein Küchen- oder ein Taschenmesser?

ist ja dasselbe wie

> Wollen Sie ein Küchenmesser oder ein Taschenmesser?

Wenn nun noch eine Schere zur Auswahl dazukommt, so heißt es

> Wollen Sie eine Schere, ein Küchenmesser oder ein Taschenmesser?

Hier meine Frage:

Wenn ich nun wieder die Kurzform einsetze, so erhalte ich

> Wollen Sie eine Schere, ein Küchen- oder ein Taschenmesser?

was meiner Meinung nach falsch klingt.

Was wäre nun korrekt? Wieso?

Comment: Laut [dieser](http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Ergaenzungsstrich.html) und [dieser Seite](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viertelgeviertstrich#Erg.C3.A4nzungsstrich) gibt es keine Ausnahme, außer es handelt sich um die Weglassung von Suffixen. Ich denke, der letzte Satz ist korrekt.

Comment: Ich denke eher wegen der Aufzählung, dass ich eher `Wollen Sie eine schere ODER ein Küchen- oder Taschenmesser?` sagen würde. @LuxxMiner

Comment: Der Satz ist völlig korrekt.

Comment: Was klingt daran falsch?

Comment: Problematisch wäre allenfalls eine Mehrdeutigkeit wie "Wollen Sie ein Brot-, ein Küchen- oder ein Taschenmesser?" im Vergleich zu "Wollen Sie ein Brot, ein Küchen- oder ein Taschenmesser?" Zwar sind Brotmesser auch Küchenmesser, aber das Filetiermesser liegt schon für die Kritiker bereit. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Der Satz

> Wollen Sie eine Schere, ein Küchen- oder ein Taschenmesser?

ist völlig korrekt. Im Fall einer Auswahl (also keiner *und*-, sondern einer *oder*-Aufzählung) ist es aber durchaus auch üblich, zwischen alle Auswahlmöglichkeiten das Wort »*oder*« einzufügen:

> Wollen Sie eine Schere **oder** ein Küchen- oder ein Taschenmesser?

Wenn dir die Reihenfolge Unbehagen bereitet, kannst du sie ja ändern:

> Wollen Sie ein Küchen- oder ein Taschenmesser oder eine Schere?

Um die Zusammengehörigkeit der beiden Messer hervorzuheben, kann man den Artikel vor dem Taschenmesser weglassen, und danach beim Sprechen eine kurze Sprechpause machen, die ich hier durch ein Komma andeute, das grammatisch aber falsch ist:

> Wollen Sie ein Küchen- oder Taschenmesser, oder eine Schere?

Von dem Komma im letzen Satz abgesehen sind aber alle hier genannten Beispiele grammatisch korrekt.